# How to sum multiple values using offset based off criteria?

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to lookup all specific text in a column and return the sum of the next cell to the right on the same row.

Let’s say example

John   600
David  700
John   800

I want to lookup John and sum the 600 and 800. This could be for a list lot larger than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `SUMIF`.

For example: `=SUMIF($G$3:$G$10, J3, $H$3:$H$10)`

[image]